# Imbalanced data set with a negative example majority using scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have an imbalanced binary data set, with a majority of 1 labels (6 to 1).

I am running GridSearchCV with a LinearSVC model using class_weight='balanced' to optimize the 'C' parameter. Because of the 1 majority, I think I need a scoring function like 'metrics.average_precision_score' with one difference: it would compute the score according to the 0 labels rather than the 1's.

1. Am I right to do so?
2. I there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer digging in the Scikit scoring functions docs.

It is possible to compute the score according to the negative label, by redefining it to be the "positive label" (for the scoring only). For example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, make scorer
# here the scoring function is created. make_scorer passes the pos_label=0
# argument to sklearn.metrics.precision_score() to create the desired function. 
neg_precision = make_scorer(precision_score, pos_label=0)
# some random C parameters for completion
params = {'C': [0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 10]}
clf = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(class_weight='balanced'), cv=10,param_grid=params, scoring=neg_precision)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

I personally decided to use scoring='f1_macro'. This computes the non-weighted average of the positive label's f1-score, and negative label's f1-score. That produced the results I was after.